How to create vnet peering between the vnet for my vm and the vnet where azure pipeline agents are hosted?
I try to run some scans on Azure pipeline agents and send the result from the scan to application hosted on a vm in an Azure virtual machine. Azure pipeline agents are Microsoft managed, but the agents don’t have a direct connection to vm.
I would like to create some kind of vnet peering between the vnet for my vm and the vnet where the azure pipeline agents are hosted. But this appeared to be also a problem. I am not aware of how to handle this problem or what would be the best way to do it.
Any help?

This looks related: https://github.com/geekzter/azure-pipeline-agents
